# datetimeoffset not posting back correctly - MomentJS

Tags: c#, jquery, html, knockout.js, momentjs

**Technologies**

KnockoutJS, Knockout Mapping Plugin, MomentJS, SQL Server, C# Web Service

**Issue**

Adding time entry via modal popup that sets the start time to 7:30am to 4:30pm.  I want this to always be the case no matter the time zone the user is in.  This appears to work fine but when I save the result via ajax it changes it to 11:30 and 20:30.  It does not include the timezone which I feel is a concern but want clarification.  I'm running local only right now so both on EST.

**Thoughts**

I want the database to show 7:30 -4:00 or is my thinking incorrect? I also need it to load back in properly also which currently it does but I'm afraid if my server/database in on Chicago time and user in EST it would not load back in properly.

**Code**

*New Time Entry*

```
self.NewTimeEntry = function () {
    var today = new Date();

    console.log(moment(moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')).add(7, 'h').add(30, 'm'));
    console.log(moment(moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')).add(16, 'h').add(30, 'm'));

    var newEntry = {
        ID: -1,
        EmployeeID: -1,
        WorkorderID: self.WorkorderID(),
        JobDate: today,
        Description: '',
        LunchBreak: 0.5,
        StartedOn: moment(moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')).add(7, 'h').add(30, 'm'),
        FinishedOn: moment(moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')).add(16, 'h').add(30, 'm')
    };
    self.EmployeeHoursModal.unshift(new EmployeeHour(self, newEntry));

    ScrollToTop('#' + self.WorkorderHoursModalID() + ' .modal-body')
}
```

*Console Results*
[image]

*Employee Hour View Model*

```
function EmployeeHour(parent, dto) {
var self = this;
dto = dto || {};
var mapping = { 'ignore': ['__type', '_type', 'type'] }

ko.mapping.fromJS(dto, mapping, self);

self.LunchBreakOptions = ko.observableArray([
    new RadioButton('No Lunch', 0, self.LunchBreak, function () { return self.LunchBreak() == 0; }),
    new RadioButton('15', .25, self.LunchBreak, function () { return self.LunchBreak() == .25; }),
    new RadioButton('30', .50, self.LunchBreak, function () { return self.LunchBreak() == .50; }),
    new RadioButton('45', .75, self.LunchBreak, function () { return self.LunchBreak() == .75; }),
    new RadioButton('1 Hour', 1, self.LunchBreak, function () { return self.LunchBreak() == 1; })
]);

self.StartedOn = ko.observable(moment(dto.StartedOn));
self.FinishedOn = ko.observable(moment(dto.FinishedOn));

self.CalculateTotal = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.StartedOn() != null && self.FinishedOn() != null) {
        var endTime = moment.utc(self.FinishedOn()).subtract((60 * self.LunchBreak()), 'm').toDate();
        var totalTime = moment.utc(moment.utc(endTime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment.utc(self.StartedOn(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))); //.format("HH:mm");
        if (parseInt(totalTime.format('HH')) == 1) {
            return parseInt(totalTime.format('HH')) + ' Hour' + ((parseInt(totalTime.format('mm')) > 0) ? ' and ' + totalTime.format('mm') + ' minutes' : '');
        } else {
            return parseInt(totalTime.format('HH')) + ' Hours' + ((parseInt(totalTime.format('mm')) > 0) ? ' and ' + totalTime.format('mm') + ' minutes' : '');
        }
    } else {
        return 'None';
    }
});
}
```

*Modal Popup*[image]

*Client Saving Code*

```
self.SaveTimeEntries = function () {
    IsSaving('time entries');

    for (var idx = 0; idx < self.EmployeeHoursModal().length; ++idx) {
        var hourDTO = {
            dto: ko.toJS(self.EmployeeHoursModal()[idx])
        };

        PostDTO('/WorkorderService.asmx/SaveJobHour', hourDTO, function (obj) {
            self.EmployeeHoursModal()[idx].ID(obj.ID);
        });
    }

    SavedSuccessfully();
}
```

*Server Saving Code*
[image]

Comment: Aaah Javascript and Dates, confusing developers since forever.
I usually save dates in utc format in the database and use moment locale.
moment.utc(utcDateString).local().format(formatString) to display it in the user's timezone.

Comment: Hi Shadowfox, yeah figuring this out has been a pain.  I traced the issue back to a library I am using for calendar and time selection.  Bootstrap DateTimePicker v3.  The date I was using was not the date it was using so we were both off.  If I get free time I will post what I discovered.